# how to use IO Monad in another Monad

Tags: haskell, monads, io-monad

I use MongoDB library to handle data from Mongodb. There is a Monad called `Action` representing a DB read or write operation `https://github.com/TonyGen/mongoDB-haskell/blob/master/doc/tutorial.md`.
But, I find that when I in monad Action, I also want to do some IO which must be in an IO Monad. Some codes like

```
-- `Action' is a Monad
--
intoFile :: String -> Cursor -> Action IO ()
intoFile ric c = do
  outH <- liftIO $ openFile ric AppendMode
  liftIO $ hPutStrLn outH "Some log"
  loopIntoFile outH c
  liftIO $ hClose outH
```

There is a `liftIO` before any `IO` monad and I think it may be verbose. Any concise way to handle this ?

Comment: There isn't really a good way to handle this since the `IO` actions are implemented solely as returning `IO a` instead of `MonadIO m => m a`.  I often see things like `where io = liftIO` on functions and the function `io` is used instead of `liftIO`, just to reduce typing.  Ideally we'd have `hPutStrLn :: MonadIO m => Handle -> String -> m ()`, but we can't expect functions from `base` to depend on classes defined in 3rd party libraries (even if those libraries are part of the haskell platform).

Comment: If you have a sequence of IO action you can change `do liftIO action1 ; liftIO action2` to `liftIO $ do action1; action2` to save some lifts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t avoid the `liftIO`, unfortunately, because the standard `IO` actions are not overloaded to work in any `MonadIO`. But you can join sequences of `IO` actions under one call to `liftIO`:

```
intoFile :: String -> Cursor -> Action IO ()
intoFile ric c = do
  outH <- liftIO $ do
    openFile ric AppendMode
    hPutStrLn outH "Some log"
  loopIntoFile outH c
  liftIO $ hClose outH
```

Or, if you intend to use the same `IO` operations repeatedly, you can introduce auxiliary definitions for them:

```
intoFile :: String -> Cursor -> Action IO ()
intoFile ric c = do
  outH <- openLog ric AppendMode
  log outH "Some log"
  loopIntoFile outH c
  closeLog outH

openLog path mode = liftIO (openFile path mode)
log handle message = liftIO (hPutStrLn handle message)
closeLog handle = liftIO (hClose handle)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to carry along 2 additional contexts - the `IO` context and `Action` context. That's the case for monad transformers, because they allow you to deal with layering monads and choose inside of `do` block which monad to choose for desired action. [Here is a great explanation](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/05/grok-haskell-monad-transformers.html) of why we need them and how to use them.